# Imitate Nesting behaviour in variable functions

Tags: lua, nested

Is it possible to have a function called inside another keep access to the local variable scoping of the function it was called inside without passing data, the same way as a nested function does?

```
function x()
    DoSomething(modified)
end
function y()
    DoSomethingElse(modified)
    DoSomethingElseToo(something)
end

local scopedFunction = x
function main(input)
    local modified = GetModifiedVersion(input)
    local something = GetSomething(modified)
    scopedFunction()
end
```

This avoids having to copy "Modified" or pack the table and transfer unnecessary data.

Comment: Passing a value to a function does not copy the value. It only passes a reference. That's why you don't have to worry about expensive copies when calling functions or assigning to variables. The best way by far to handle this is to have `x` and `y` take parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Closures

> Is it possible to have a function called inside another keep access to the local variable scoping of the function it was called inside [...]

Yes.

> [...] without passing data, the same way as a nested function does?

The "nested function" is in that case called a closure and the variables that enter the closure's scope are called "upvalues" of the function. Example:

```lua
local function outer()
    local var = "hello world"
    local function closure()
        print(var)
    end
    closure() -- will print "hello world"
end
```

note that these upvalues are references to the variables, not copies of them! So modifying the variable even after creating the closure works just fine:

```lua
local function outer()
    local var = "hello world"
    local function closure()
        print(var)
    end
    closure() -- will print "hello world"
    var = "new value"
    closure() -- will print "new value"
end
```

So my first question would be: Why can't you use a closure here? Are you afraid of the cost of creating a new closure each function call? The alternatives - aside from passing the variables - won't be much cheaper:

## Shared upvalue

You could make `var` a shared upvalue, setting it before calling the "inner" function:

```lua
local var
local function callee()
    print(var)
end
local function caller()
    var = "hello world"
    callee() -- will print "hello world"
end
```

The disadvantage of this is that `var` bleeds into the enclosing scope of the two functions. You could use a `do`-`end` block to prevent this.

## Shared (usually global) environment

You don't even need to use an upvalue for this - you can just use the (usually global) environment both functions reside in:

```lua
local function callee()
    print(var)
end
local function caller()
    var = "hello world"
    callee() -- will print "hello world"
end
```

I would heavily recommend against this kind of so-called "global pollution" as the global environment will bleed into the scope of *everything*; in a constrained function environment this *might* be fine, but still you probably won't want to constantly index a table.

## Function environments & `debug` hacks

Finally it is even possible to implement exactly the kind of scoping you're looking for by abusing the `debug` library - specifically its `getlocal` & `setlocal` functions as well as the `getinfo` function to get the function currently on the stack; you'll have to furthermore set the environment to one that leverages this by setting an `__[new]index` metatable which accesses the appropriate locals (or filling the environment table) `_ENV` of your function (you'd have to use `setfenv` for this on Lua 5.1, LuaJIT and older).

I am not providing the code for this as it is both (1) horribly inefficient and (2) a major code smell, but making the below work in Lua is possible:

```lua
-- implementing inherit_local_var_env is left as an exercise to the reader
local function callee()
    _ENV = inherit_local_var_env()
    print(var) -- accesses local var from the calling function
end
local function caller()
    local var = "hello world"
    callee() -- will print "hello world"
end
local function another_caller()
    local var = "another message"
    callee() -- will print "another message"
end
```